# Monitor if a popup window is visible in a Coded UI Test for a win32 application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I currently have a win 32 application which emits popup windows based on different parameters.

I an trying to write a test that is able to act if the window is visible. if not I want my test to continue without failing.

Are there any examples available?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check using (YourWindow).Exists property.

For example,

```
if (MyPopupWindow.Exists)
    Mouse.Click(MyPopupWindow.dxDialogOkButton());
```

Comment: good point, without forgetting to map the popup windows first